# Conversion image links to base64 and adding them to zip file using JSZip

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, base64, jszip

So basically I want to add few images to zip file and be able to download it. I have two variables holding sources of images - **pic1, pic2** and a global variable **basePic** for holding base64 string. I have a function to convert image to base64 :

```
var pic; //http://www.somesite.com/i/picture.jpg
var pic2; //http://www.somesite.com/i/picture2.jpg
var basePic;// base64 string of an image

function getBase64FromImageUrl(url) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

    img.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width =this.width;
    canvas.height =this.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    basePic=dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");  
    }; 

    img.src = url; // I was trying to put this after setAttribute, but it's the same effect
    }
```

Later I'm trying to create a zip file and invoke this function like that:

```
var zip = new JSZip();

getBase64FromImageUrl(pic);
alert("random text"); // without it, it's just empty file added to zip
zip.file("picture.png",basePic, {base64: true});

getBase64FromImageUrl(pic2);
alert("random text");
zip.file("picture2.png",basePic, {base64: true});

zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
.then(function(content) {
saveAs(content, "example.zip");
});
```

This function works with one image, but it get's more random with more than one. If I run my code few times without refreshing the page it may get the result that I need. But most of the time in my zip file is just only second picture twice and I have to **alert** something after calling this function, because **basePic** would be empty without. I want to fix this function to be able, to easily convert multiple sources of images to base64 strings.

**1.How to make this function work as it should, input_url -> output_base64, with multiple images ?**

**2.How to do that without the need to alert something after every call of that function ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the zipping process starts before the image(s) has loaded. The process of adding the files to the zip archive must start from inside the `onload` handler.

However, there are several things to consider here as well:

- If you want to add images as-is to the archive there is no need to go via canvas
- Converting to and from Data-URIs are very expensive and memory costly. JSZip uses pako_delate internally which works much better with typed array views (`Uint8Array`)

I would propose the following approach instead:

- Create zip object at beginning of app (or before starting loading files)
- Load each file using `XMLHttpRequest`s and request content as `ArrayBuffer`. This will allow you to load any kind of file directly to binary format which will increase performance and resources.
- Add files as they come
- When all URLs are passed call the `generateAsync()` method and you should be done.

### Example

This is not a production-ready example and isn't intended to be, but it will show the main steps. Adjust to your scenario, add error handling and sanity checks where appropriate.

```js
// create archive before loading process begin
var zip = new JSZip();

// image list to add:
var images = [
      "//i.imgur.com/qDFCWVnb.jpg",
      "//i.imgur.com/VBvzEq1b.jpg",
      "//i.imgur.com/ZWtUEuLb.jpg"
    ],
    index = 0;  // for loader

// function to load a single image as arraybuffer using XMLHttpRequests
// it will assume cross-origin usage is allowed
function loadAsArrayBuffer(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url);
  xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
  xhr.onerror = function() {/* handle errors*/};
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {callback(xhr.response, url)}
    else {/* handle errors*/}
  };
  xhr.send();
}

// loading process. Here it will load one and one image.
// You can modify it to load several at once but some browsers put
// a cap on how many XHR connections can be open at the same time..
(function load() {
  if (index < images.length) {
    loadAsArrayBuffer(images[index++], function(buffer, url) {
      var filename = getFilename(url);
      zip.file(filename, buffer); // image has loaded, add it to archive
      load();                     // load next image
    })
  }
  else {                          // done! present archive somehow
    zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {
      // save out
      lnk.href = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(content);
      lnk.innerHTML = "Right-click + Save as to download zip file";
      lnk.download = "DemoZip.zip";
    });
  }
})();

// Just for this demo! keep separate array with filename or
// modify to allow for "filename-less" uris.
function getFilename(url) {
  return url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Stuk/jszip/master/dist/jszip.min.js"></script>
Loading external lib + images... hold on...
<br><a id=lnk></a>
```

Comment: In my example main problem is in function converting image to base64, even before adding to zip. I was kinda hoping to fix that function, but I'm gonna try your solution and see if it's gonna work.

Comment: Thx, works fine, even with AJAX and more images, but still I have to make one 'alert()' call, before saving a file in order to get proper amount of objects to zip. I guess it's a problem with asynchronity. It's amajor improvement, but any thoughts how to simulate 'alert()',  to make compiler wait for all objects before trying to make a zip file ??

Comment: @markE sorry to disappoint you, but no, this is related to something *different* (as stated at the time). :)