# JSZip imgData is not defined

Tags: javascript, jszip

```js
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");

var img = zip.folder("images");
img.file(images[0], imgData, {base64: true});

zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {
    // see FileSaver.js
    saveAs(content, "example.zip");
});
```

Running the code above I get an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: imgData is not defined

How can I make it functional? I tried to find more info regarding it in the documentation but I couldn't find anything. I assume this should just work out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

`imgData` is just a placeholder. It can be retrieved using different methods, however I used fetch like this:

```js
const fetchData = (file) => 
  fetch(file)
  .then((res) => res.blob());
```

then:

```
const data = fetchData(imagesource);
```

then:

```
zip.file("filename.fileextension", data, { base64: true });
  zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function (blob) {
    saveAs(blob, "zipname.zip");
```

for more information and methods check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208096/conversion-image-links-to-base64-and-adding-them-to-zip-file-using-jszip)